# python3 scapy - sending packets to network 127.0.0.0/8

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm struggling for a few days how to send packets from scapy to network 127.0.0.0. On the computer ( linux ) are configured 2 IP addressess 127.0.0.4 and 127.0.0.7. I can ping them. Theses addressess (127.0.0.04 and .7) are not configured as a interfaces so if i will type "ip a" they are not shown. It looks like both of them are configured on the application side as services.
Using scapy I'm sending packet from 127.0.0.4 to 127.0.0.7 and packet is shown in tcpdump but there is no any response and it looks like packet is not reaching target IP ( 127.0.0.7).

```
(...)
conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
(...)
sendp(packet,iface='lo')
```

If I use netfilterque and match both IP and then modify packet from 127.0.0.4 to 127.0.0.7 and finally accept packet I do have response from 127.0.0.7.

Does any1 have any idea how to send properly packet to 127.0.0.0/8 network with scapy or am I missing something ?

regards